# Como hago pasar este UnitTest?

Tags: c++

```
    TEST_METHOD(TestBookReferenceCreation) {
        BookReference* book = new BookReference("Alexandre Bergel", "Agile Visualization", 2012,"lulu",1);
        Assert::IsTrue(book->isBook());
        Assert::IsFalse(book->isArticle());
        Assert::IsTrue(book->getTitle() == "Agile Visualization");
    }
```

Tengo una clase padre llamada Reference y sus clases derivadas son BookReference y ArticleReference
ambas deben contener los metodos isBook() e isArticle()
cada que se crea un BookReference de por si "isBook()" deberia saber que en efecto el objeto creado book es un libro y no un articulo.
Mi duda en resumen es como hago para  que  "isBook()" sepa que book  es un libro sin cambiarle nada al test.

P.D: estoy en visual c++

Comment: ¿ BookReference tiene alguna función-miembro virtual ?

Comment: no porque no es padre de ninguna otra clase.  Supongo que en la clase padre Reference  el isBook seria un virtual abstracto.

Comment: Cierto, me refería a esa. ¿ Supones ? ¿ Las claes no son tuyas ?

Comment: Esto huele a ejercicio de clase. El problema es que aquí no se hacen deberes sino que se resuelven problemas concretos. Intenta resolver el problema por tus propios medios y pregunta aquí cuando hayas intentado algo y te atasques

Comment: las clases si las hice yo.en realidad estuve haciendo una serie de ejercicios de practica propuestos por mi docente para un examen que tengo mañana y este ejercicio es el mas completo. tiene mas tests que ya hice pasar. Solo quiero saber que tiene que devolver  isBook para que el assertTrue lo reconozca.

Comment: Tiene que devolver `true`, como bien te dice el *assert*